# Loading child nodes within the same transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a TreeNode entity that points to itself with `OneToMany` relationship. We also need previous and next relations between siblings for navigation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "hierarchy", 
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "node",
        referencedColumnName = "id")) })
public class TreeNode {

  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String id;

  @Column
  private String label;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent", table = "hierarchy")
  private TreeNode parent;

  @Column(table = "hierarchy", name = "previous")
  private String previous;

  @Column(name = "next", table = "hierarchy")
  private String next;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "hierarchy", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parent",
      referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "node",
      referencedColumnName = "id")})
  private Set<TreeNode> nodes = new HashSet<>();

  @Column(name = "updated_dt")
  private Timestamp updatedDate;

  public TreeNode getLastChild() {
    for (TreeNode node : nodes) {
      if (node.getNext() == null) {
        return node;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
   // getter, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

I am trying to load the complete tree structure from a tab separated file where each line represents one new node.
For instance,

```
T1
T1   T2
T1   T2   T3
T1   T2   T4
```

Following is the code to load the records.

```
@Transactional
public void loadTree(Scanner lines) {

while (lines.hasNextLine()) {
  final String line = lines.nextLine();
  try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line)) {
    Iterator<String> nodes = scanner.useDelimiter("\t");
    addChildNodes(nodes);
  }
}
}

private TreeNode addChildNodes(final Iterator<String> nodes) {
TreeNode parentNode = null;
while (nodes.hasNext()) {
  String nodeTerm = nodes.next();

  if (!StringUtils.hasText(nodeTerm)) {
    continue;
  }

  String id = generateId(parentNode, nodeTerm);
  TreeNode node = repo.findOne(id);
  if (node == null) {
    node = new TreeNode(id, nodeTerm);
    node.setParent(parentNode);
    TreeNode previous = null;
    if (parentNode != null)
      previous = parentNode.getLastChild();
    if (previous != null) {
      node.setPrevious(previous.getId());
      previous.setNext(node.getId());
    }
    node = repo.saveAndFlush(node);
    if (previous != null) {
      previous = repo.save(previous);
    }
  }
  parentNode = node;
}
return parentNode;
```

}

But the problem is that the `nodes` list is never loaded, due to which `getLastChild` always return empty list, and `previous` and `next` values are never set. Why is the lazy loading of `nodes` not working? I tried it eager loading, but not working. Alternatively, I am creating new transaction for each find and save, but it is very slow, and the select queries keep on increasing as the tree size increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entities in `TreeNode.nodes` are not being loaded because there's nothing to load. You haven't declared either side of the association as the inverse side, so JPA treats it as two separate associations (and you never set `TreeNode.nodes`). If that was your intention, then you need to set `TreeNode.nodes` explicitly. Otherwise, you want `mappedBy` with `@OneToMany`, and you cannot use both `@JoinColumn`and `@JoinTable`.

You seem to be working against (rather than with) JPA. I'm not sure how `TreeNode.previous` and `TreeNode.next` are supposed to work, but using a table for both a secondary and a join table is a baaaad idea. I don't even think the behavior of JPA is well-defined for such a case. Anyway, why not make them two one-to-one, lazily fetched associations?

Answer (score 0):

You call `setParent` in exactly one place:

node.setParent(parentNode);

`parentNode` in turn is again set only in one place:

`TreeNode parentNode = null;`

So the parent of a node never ever get set to anything but `null`.